# Parse.com SignUpAsync Unity is returning 403 Forbidden

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, parse-platform

I'm trying to get user sign up and log in on parse.com working in Unity.
I have the ParseInitializeBehaviour in place and I can call SaveAsync() successfully so I know that's working.

If I call LogInAsync() it throws a ParseException of 404 Not Found.

Then when I try and sign up using the example code they provide it throws a fault where the message is '403 Forbidden'. Any clue where I'm going wrong?

```
private void signUp() {
    var user = new ParseUser() {
        Username = "my name",
        Password = "my pass",
        Email = "email@example.com"
    };

    Task signUpTask = user.SignUpAsync().ContinueWith(task => {
        if (task.IsFaulted) {
            foreach (ParseException parseException in task.Exception.InnerExceptions) {
                Debug.Log("ParseManager.signUpNewUser fault code: " + parseException.Code + ", Message " + parseException.Message);
            }
        }
        else if (task.IsCanceled) {
            print("ParseManager.signUpNewUser cancel ");
        }
        else {
            print("ParseManager.signUpNewUser success ParseUser.CurrentUser:" + ParseUser.CurrentUser);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I had turned off write permission for the User class in the Data Browser.

To fix it go to Core > Data in the Parse admin area.
Select the 'User' class
Then click on 'Security' and make sure both Read and Write is enabled, then click 'Save CLP'